# Generate images from within the code in an array

Tags: arrays, image, delphi

So I'm writing this program where I need to translate a rhtyhm tapped on a key into notes. 
The problem I'm having is setting the notes down on the screen. Since I'll probably need a lot of notes, I'll have to use an array, and need a way to conjure up these images from the code. 
What I have up until now to make the right note appear on the screen:

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  for teller3 := 0 to teller2 - 1 do 
  begin

    if maal[teller3]=1 then 
      Image1.picture.loadFromFile('E:\Informatica\Eindopdracht\Afbeeldingen\nootachtste.jpg');

    if maal[teller3]=2 then 
      Image1.picture.loadFromFile('E:\Informatica\Eindopdracht\Afbeeldingen\nootkwart.jpg');

    if maal[teller3]=4 then 
      Image1.picture.loadFromFile('E:\Informatica\Eindopdracht\Afbeeldingen\noothalf.jpg');

    if maal[teller3]=8 then 
      Image1.picture.loadFromFile('E:\Informatica\Eindopdracht\Afbeeldingen\nootheel.jpg');

  end;
end;
```

Here is 'maal' the amount of times that the smallest time in the array fitted in a particular time.
But this way I can only put one note on the screen. So how would I adapt this code to put the right note on the screen for every time in the array?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't do it this way. Using `TImage` is fine for static images. You are going to want to draw an arbitrary number. And presumably add bar indicators if not staves. You'll be wanting to paint this directly with, say, a `TPaintBox`.